# Extending maps between surfaces to maps between handlebodies

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I am given two handlebodies $H_g$ and $H_h$ and a continuous map $f : \partial H_g \to \partial H_h$ - under what conditions is it possible to extend $f$ to a map $F : H_g \to H_h$?  Is it sufficient for null simple closed curves in $\partial H_g$ that bound disks in $H_g$ to be mapped by $f$ to simple closed curves in $\partial H_h$ that bound disks in $H_h$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that suffices, because once you extend it over those discs, it suffices to extend it over the complement of the boundary and those discs, which is a 3-ball. Because handlebodies are aspherical, every map from a 2-sphere extends to a map from a 3-ball.

Comment: @MikeMiller why don't you post this text as an answer?